# Filtering Laravel eloquent collections with filter method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
  $events=Event::all();
  if (isset($scheduling) && $scheduling!=="All")
  {
     $events = $events->filter(function($event) use ($scheduling)
     {
        return $event->where('scheduling',$scheduling);
      });
   }
  $events=$events->get();
```

can some one correct this code. the inner filter is not working. the results are same with or without applying filters. i need to apply lot filters like this basing on conditions

Comment: It might be that last line, where you re-assign $events.

Comment: i have lot of filters one after the other.i think  it wont be a good idea to create such number new variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to use where condition in it, you can just return `true` or `false` from within `callback`, depending on the selection condition.

Below code will keep only those `events`that pass a given truth test:

```
   $events=Event::all();

   if (isset($scheduling) && $scheduling!=="All") 
   {  
      $events = $events->filter(function($event) use ($scheduling)
      {
         return $event->scheduling == $scheduling;
       });
    }

   dd($events); //Collection
```

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter)

Comment: How to check if $scheduling in an aray

Answer (score 4):

The other answer correctly explains why what you're doing isn't working, but here is another option.

Instead of pulling everything from the database and then applying filters to the collection, you can use the builder to let the database do the filtering.

```
$query = Event::query();
if (isset($scheduling) && $scheduling !== "All") {
    $query = $query->where('scheduling', '=', $scheduling);
}
// add more wheres as needed
$events = $query->get();
```

Comment: How do you use that method right from the Model class? I mean, if you set up a method inside the Model class